# Minimizing a quadratic function subject to a quadratic constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors, convex-optimization

It is required to minimize the quadratic function

$f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^T Q \mathbf{x} + b^T \mathbf{x} + c $

Subject to the quadratic constraint

$ g(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^T C \mathbf{x} + d^T \mathbf{x} + e = 0$

where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and it is assumed that matrix $C$ is positive definite.

**My approach** is based on the Lagrange multiplier method, so I define

$ L(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda \ g(\mathbf{x}) $

Then we want

$ \nabla L = \nabla f + \lambda \nabla g = \mathbf{0}$

which translates into

$ \nabla L = \mathbf{0} = 2 Q \mathbf{x} + b + \lambda \ (2 C \mathbf{x} + d ) $

I am not sure how to proceed from this point.  One way I can think of is to isolate $\mathbf{x}$,

$\mathbf{x} = - ( 2 Q + 2 \lambda C )^{-1} (b + \lambda d ) $

Substituting this into $g(\mathbf{x}) = 0 $ gives

$ (b + \lambda \ d )^T ( 2Q + 2 \lambda C )^{-1} C ( 2 Q + 2 \lambda C)^{-1} (b + \lambda \ d ) - d^T (2 Q + 2 \lambda C )^{-1} (b + \lambda d ) + e = 0 $

But I have no idea how I would solve for $\lambda$ from this equation.  Would it possible to apply the matrix inversion lemma (Woodbury matrix identity) to simplify this equation ?

Another way to go, which I think is better, is to eliminate $\lambda$

We have

$\mathbf{0} = 2 Q \mathbf{x} + b + \lambda \ (2 C \mathbf{x} + d ) $

So,

$ 2 Q \mathbf{x} + b = -\lambda \ (2 C \mathbf{x} + d ) $

If we define

$ E_j = e_1 e_j^T - e_j e_1^T,  \ j = 2,3, \dots , n $

Then

$ (2 Q \mathbf{x} + b )^T E_j (2 C \mathbf{x} + d) = 0 , \ j = 2, 3, \dots, n$

This is a quadratic system of $(n-1)$ quadratic equation in the unknown vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^n$, in addition to these, we have the $n$-th equation which is $g(\mathbf{x}) = 0 $.

Now we can use a quadratic system solver to obtain all possible solutions. (*Mathematica* should be able to solve this system).  Having obtained all the possible solutions, we select the one that gives the minimum value of $f(\mathbf{x})$.
I appreciate your comments, hints, and alternative solutions.